# Textbox dynamic placeholder doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

placeholder doesn't get the result of `LANGU("ProveType")` and paste the code directly as `<%= LANGU("ProveType") %>`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" placeholder='<%= LANGU("ProveType") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What you are doing with LANGU?. Secondly, are you want to bind the value to placeholder using ASP.NET server?

Comment: It brings language specific text,and yes I am want*

Comment: Just to confirm, is it your server side function to get the language specific code? I mean if you want to use the language specific placeholder, why don't you use App_LocalResources for multi-language support?